# Which portlet_2_0.tld is best to use?

Tags: portlet, portal, websphere-portal

We have many vendor specific "portlet_2_0.tld" files for portlet development. I am developing portlets with JSR 286 standard. I want my portlet to be deployed into all the portal servers. In case if i use vendor specific tld files, then my portlet will be deviated from standard.

Here, I looking for information like which tld file is best for standard portlet development.

Some of the TLD files below,

sun-portlet_2_0.tld - from Sun, 
liferay-portlet.tld - from liferay, XXX - may be from some other vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of tag library is a part of JSR 286 (http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286). The Portal vendor impliments the specification, so if you use only the

`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>` you can deploy this portlet on each portal implementation that support JSR 286